# Angular Disable Before Directive Call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've ran into a bit of a challenge in my AngularJS app. I have a form that users can fill out. When they submit, a directive that I've downloaded from Bower takes over, does a POST in the background and then returns to my scope function to finish up. I need to disable the button that is clicked and show a loading img when they click the submit button. Normally, setting an 'updating' variable in the scope would take care of this:

```
    <input data-ng-disabled="form.isUpdating" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    <img data-ng-show="form.isUpdating" src="/images/spinner.gif">

     $scope.saveForm = function (){
        $scope.form.isUpdating = true;
        // Do some stuff
        $scope.form.isUpdating = false;
     }
```

The problem I have is that I don't have control over what happens initially, because the directive takes over, which has no access to my scope. I could mess with the code, but I would rather not if I don't have to. So when I click the button to submit, nothing happens until the POST in the directive is complete, which is not good for my user.

I can't do an ng-click and set form.isUpdating to true there, because that immediately makes the button disabled so the click doesn't register. You can't use ng-click and ng-disabled together as far as I know.

Can anyone think of a good way to get around this?

Comment: I don't see any issues with using ng-click. Do you face any issues using ng-click and then disbling the button on ng-click?

Comment: Yea, from what I've read (and experienced) when using ng-click to set a variable, that is set first, so setting form.isUpdating to true immediately disables the form, so the button is disabled, img is there, but nothing else is triggered.

Comment: how do you configure/set up this 3rd party directive? ngMousedown will be the first event fired in a mousedown, mouseup, click, submit event sequence. Can you wrap the ngsubmit?

Comment: On form submit the directive takes over I don't configure anything at all. The form simply needs to be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Do the stuff you need to get done async. this will put it outside the current
digest cycle.
like this:

```
 $scope.saveForm = function (){
    $scope.form.isUpdating = true;
    $timeout(function () {
        //this will run outside the current
        //digest cycle, so the UI has a change of updating
        // while I'm working!
        // Do some stuff
        $scope.form.isUpdating = false;
    },0)
 }
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: That's good but the issue is that the code that is taking the time is going on before the saveForm function is triggered. I need to set isUpdating before getting to the saveForm function.

Comment: You code seemed to indicate the saveForm function to be the curlpit. Can you build a plunk/fiddle illustrating your problem, I can probably help then!

Comment: Create a button that uses my code, and triggers the submit via code, I think that's the easiest way around your issue.